# Syntax error in Perl script

Tags: perl

I'm essentially copy/pasting code from a website that details how to interact via Perl with the Cisco Ironport API.  Here is my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use Cisco::IronPort;

    $username=$ARGV[0];chomp $username;
    $password=$ARGV[1];chomp $password;
    $server="prodironport1-mgt.abc.com:83";
    $server2="prodironport2-mgt.abc.com:83";

    my $ironport = Cisco::IronPort->new(
                      username => $username,
                      password => $password,
                      server => $server
                   );

    my %stats = $ironport->incoming_mail_details_current_hour;

    foreach my $domain (keys %stats) {
        if (    ( $stats{$domain}{total_attempted} > 50 ) 
            and ( int (($stats{$domain}{spam_detected}/$stats{$domain}{total_attempted})*100) > 50 
           ) 
    {
       print "Domain $domain sent "
           . $stats{$domain}{total_attempted}
           . " messages, "
           . $stats{$domain}{spam_detected} 
           . " were marked as spam.\n"
     }
    }
```

and here is the error that I get:

```
syntax error at ./Ironport5.pl line 21, near ") {"
syntax error at ./Ironport5.pl line 24, near "}"
Execution of ./Ironport5.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I'm sure it is something simple, but I very much appreciate any help.

Thank you,

Dave

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after your `print` statement.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, nope, he's not. Semi-colons aren't needed at the end of a block/file.

Comment: @ikegami: Well, it's true that there is no semicolon there, but it's not required in that particular context. (IMHO using a semicolon is better style, but that's not the point here.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson, I never said one was present; I said none was missing.

Comment: @ikegami That's new to me, thanks. Keith, I think you're agreeing with ikegami.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes, I'm agreeing with ikegami.

Comment: @ikegami: Understood. Just to recurse one more level, I never said that you said one was present. But another reader might incorrectly assume that that's what you were saying. I agree with what you wrote; I'm just trying to add a bit of clarity.

Comment: Working now...thank you all very much.

Answer (score 3):

You have 5 opening parens, but only 4 closing parens.

```
if (   ( ... )
   and ( int(...) > 50
)
```

should be

```
if (   ( ... )
   and ( int(...) > 50 )
)
```

Comment: you are correct, ikegami! There is a closing parenthesis missing at the end of the condition portion of the **if** block, right before the opening curly bracket... more or less what the error message said ..